# I can open the function from another class but no effect ... Why?

Tags: java, swing

this my code .....

```
public class A {

JLabel A = new JLabel() ;

public JLabel newform(){
 A.setBounds(0 , 197, 409, 245);
 A.setIcon(createImageIcon("/Pictures/BG.png"));
   return A; }          

       public void swinginDown_NF ( ){
             AnimationClass AC = new AnimationClass();  
             AC.jLabelYDown(A.getY(), 270, 6, 1,A);
        }
```

class B ....

```
public class B {
JLabel B = new JLabel() ;

public JLabel Box(){
 B.setBounds(170 , 197, 409, 245);
 B.setIcon(createImageIcon("/Pictures/BBD.png"));
 B.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                    public final void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    A a_class = new A();    
                    a_class.swinginDown_NF();
                    } });  

   return B; }
```

Main...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(" AA ");

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setUndecorated(true);

 JLabel Label = new JLabel() ;

 A a = new A();
 B b = new B()  ;



 Label.add(B.Box());

 Label.add(A.newform());

 frame.getContentPane().add( Label , BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

My problem when I click in label Box nothing happen in label newform ...

when I click in label Box function swingDown_NF its open but the label doesnt go  down ...... Why ???

Comment: the B class makes it's own instance of the A class and calls the method on that instead of the one added to the JFrame. You should send the instance of the A class added to the screen to B so it can use that to call methods on.

Comment: yes , you are right ,  its work thank you very match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new A object within the swinging down method, one that is completely separate and unique from the displayed object, and so changing the state of the new object will have no effect on the displayed one. You'll have to pass in a reference of the displayed one to where it's needed. For example you could have the B class accept an A parameter in its constructor.

Some side recommendations:

- Please learn and follow Java naming and formatting conventions as your code is very difficult to follow.
- You have class and field with the same names, A and B. Again, this will only confuse us and the future you -- never do this.
- Avoid null layouts and setBounds if at all possible as it leads to very rigid and hard to debug GUI's. Instead use layout managers.
- Your posted code won't compile. It looks like you've tried to simplify your real code for this post which is fine, but in the process you've posted bad non-compilable code including calling an instance method as if it were static. Yes, do simplify your code, but please don't post bad code in the process since you want us to understand your code and your problem well.